# concatenating string in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to concatenate image url (string) with img tag but i am not sure how to put " after src=. Please help to concatenate this.

```
response.write("<img src=" & '"' & rs("ProductImage") & '"' &" /><br/>")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to double up the quotes:

```
Response.Write("<img src=""" & rs("ProductImage") & """ /><br/>")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since HTML can use double quotes or single quotes, why not just use single quotes for the HTML.  So your code would look like this:

```
response.write("<img src='" & rs("ProductImage") & "' /><br/>")
```

The resulting output would look like this:

```
<img src='ProductImageUrl' /><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the chr function:

```
Response.Write("<img src=" & chr(34) & rs("ProductImage") & chr(34) & " /><br/>")
```

ascii code 34 is the double quote. We use this all the time when writing out HTML.